# How to disable web content appears in iframe of slide in iframe element?

Tags: iframe

see the snap shot and you will understand what i mean.

[image]

Comment: I dont't understand what you mean

Answer (score 0):

You should locate the iframe on the page using your browser's code inspection (`CTRL` + `U` generally), and then use jQuery (because its convenient) to remove it. So you should add a script like that in your page: `$(function() { $('#pubPath').remove(); });` or switch to another website.